# Can ansible be used to run ruby/rails console queries on multiple servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ansible

Can ansible be used to run ruby/rails console queries on multiple servers. Is there any other tool which can serve this purpose. Developers run lot of console queries to get information from different database. Is there any way we can use a tool so that they can do their tasks independently without depending on others.

Answer (score 0):

I have never been a rails user, but from my understanding the `rails console` is an interactive process. If I read the docs correctly the `rails runner` command is for running single commands and that makes more sense in context of automation.

So you should be able to define a task like this in a playbook.

```
- shell: rails runner <some-command>
```

Though...

> Developer run lot of console queries to get information from different database.

This more sounds like these are no pre-defined queries but arbitrary things a developer might want to run against multiple machines. Then simply use the ansible command and not ansible-playbook:

```
ansible all -m shell -a "rails runner <some-command>"
```

> Is there any other tool which can serve this purpose.

If this is your only use case [pdsh](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pdsh/) might be a bit more easy to use

```
pdsh -w host1,host2,hostN "rails runner <some-command>"
```